# fastest way to get parent array key in multidimensional arrays with php

Tags: php, search, multidimensional-array, key, performance

what is the best way to get parent array key with multidimensional arrays?
for example I have this array:

```
array(

    [0] => array(0=> sample, 1=>picture, 2=>frame, 3=>google)

    [1] => array(0=> iphone, 1=>orange, 2=>love, 3=>msn)

    [2] => array(0=> joe, 1=>geee, 2=>panda, 3=>yahoo)
)
```

now I need to search for example google and get the parent array key..
which it should be 0...any ideas? I used for loop for this but I think it will be slow if I have arrays with 700000 rows..

Comment: yes it will be slow, no matter of the way. You have to think of your data size, not of the fastest way to dig this amount

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have an array with 700,000 rows you are almost certainly doing something wrong... I would first recomend thinking about utilizing a different data store: flat file or some type of DB.

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if(in_array('google', $value)) return $key
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Arrays with 700,000 rows? How many arrays? 9/10 times problem is that you've got your data set up wrongly.

I'm going to go ahead and assume you're doing a search of some sort. As you can't index an array (in the *search* meaning of index) then you're probably best putting the data into a database and making the most of column indexing to search fast.

Depending on context, you may alternatively want to think about storing your data in files, one per array, and using file searches to find which file contains your value.

Comment: I strongly agree, an indexed table in SQL/MySQL would be highly preferable over an array of that size.

Comment: I dont want to use databases (for some reasons)..
I want Quick and Dirty solution.

Comment: A database probably is the quickest solution, if you're doing the task repeatedly. Really quick and dirty? Use a spreadsheet.