# using array_search() to find values in php

Tags: php

Im trying to search a array and navigate to the next and previous values

```
$ids=$res->result_array();
```

returns

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["qid"]=>
    string(5) "63697"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["qid"]=>
    string(5) "63706"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["qid"]=>
    string(5) "63709"
  }
}
```

but when i try to search for the index it returns false

```
$curr_index = array_search($this->uri->segment(4), $q);
```

returns

```
bool(false)
```

$this->uri->segment(4) is the qid.

i want to navigate with the array by increasing and decreasing by one so i can get the next and previous values.

can someone please tell what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: your array is multidimensional. array_search will search the first level only and that consists of array, array, array. Also, please point out why none of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=search+multidimensional+array+php answered your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP search for Key in multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388967/php-search-for-key-in-multidimensional-array)

Comment: @Gordon i didnt notice the second one and most of the replies i saw didnt have the array_search(). Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array of arrays, you could search it like this:

```
$curr_index = array_search(array('qid' => $this->uri->segment(4)), $q);
```

Where you are actually searching for an array instead of a string.

Working example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Ff0sAq