# Php Get the key of a array based in a string

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to search by key=>value in a multidimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019076/how-to-search-by-key-value-in-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)
>   [PHP search for Key in multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388967/php-search-for-key-in-multidimensional-array)

How can I search in a array values and get the key?

Example:
search for id 1 = key 0
or 
search for name Frank = key 1

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Bob
        [url] => http://www.bob.com.br
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Frank
        [url] => http://www.frank.com.br
    )
)
```

Thks.
Adriano

Comment: There [are many examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+search+multidimensional+array) to choose from

Comment: tks Michael.. the (PHP search for Key in multidimensional array) post resolved my problem...

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

```
foreach($array as $value) {
    $result = array_search('Frank', $value);
    if($result !== false) break;
}
echo $result
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know the depth, you can do something like the following, which employs the use of RecursiveIteratorIterator and RecursiveArrayIterator:

```
<?php
/*******************************
*   array_multi_search
*
*   @array  array to be searched
*   @input  search string
*
*   @return array(s) that match
******************************/
function array_multi_search($array, $input){
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));  

    foreach($iterator as $id => $sub){
        $subArray = $iterator->getSubIterator();  

        if(@strstr(strtolower($sub), strtolower($input))){
    $subArray = iterator_to_array($subArray);
            $outputArray[] = array_merge($subArray, array('Matched' => $id));
        }
    }  

    return $outputArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

don't think there is a predifned function for that,
but here is one:

```
function sub_array_search($array, $sub_key, $value, $strict = FALSE)
{
   foreach($array as $key => $sub_array)
   {
      if($sub_array[$sub_key] == $value)
      {
         if(!$strict OR $sub_array[$sub_key] === $value)
         {
            return $key;
         }
      }
   }

   return FALSE;
}
```