# get next and previous elements of PHP multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a list in php with the following structure:

```
$center = '2';

$all = array(
   array(
     'foo'=>'abc',
     'bar'=>'def',
     'order' => 2 
   ),
   array(
     'foo'=>'abc',
     'bar'=>'def',
     'order' => 5 
   ),
   array(
     'foo'=>'abc',
     'bar'=>'def',
     'order' => 11 
   ),
  //..etc
);
```

what I'd like to do is get the array before and after the array where order == $center. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [fastest way to get parent array key in multidimensional arrays with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776107/fastest-way-to-get-parent-array-key-in-multidimensional-arrays-with-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$idx = 0;
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['order'] == $center) {
        $idx = $key; 
        break;
    }
}

$before = $all[$idx - 1];
$current = $all[$idx];
$after = $all[$idx + 1];
```

If $center matches the first or last element of the array, though, before or after won't be valid -- what do you want to consider the "before" and "after" elements? Should the array be treated as a circular structure?

Comment: what if there is no `$idx ± 1`?

Comment: GSto has to define this behavior, not me, someone who doesn't know what this structure represents or what the code is to be used for.

Answer (score 0):

I would say

```
counter = 0;
foreach($all as $order){
    if($order['order'] == $center){
        break;
    }
    counter += 1;
}

$prev    = $all[$counter -1];
$current = $all[$counter ];
$next    = $all[$counter +1];
```

Comment: $center is the target value of order in the subarray, not an index into the outer array

Comment: Even with that being the case, just do a loop through your arrays and find the array with `order==11` .. then use that index in Jeff's answer in place of `$center`